# Using "dp" and "sp" in drawing

Tags: android, drawing, sizing

I'm trying to make a little app that has a little meter in it (think like a speedometer).  Well, for the pointer (you know what I'm talking about), I want to make it an 1/8th of an inch thick, independent of the display size.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think dp should be used for drawings, dimensions etc, and sp for font sizes, you can do trial-n-error and check in the emulator.. and use that DP size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` (inches) as your unit instead.

Comment: Well what function/class would I have to use to get the screen size (in inches)?